# How do change the default monitor arrangement on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, display

I'm using Windows XP (SP3) on a IBM/Lenovo ThinkPad T60, and whenever I dock the secondary monitor activates, but is positioned to the right of the main monitor.  Is there any way I can change this default behavior?  I do have Lenovo's screen manager utility installed, but I avoid using it at all costs.

Note: I'm manually rearranging the monitors every time I dock right now, but I'd like it to *default* to my normal arrangement.

[Related Question (Server 2008)](https://superuser.com/questions/3014/second-monitor-on-laptop-external-monitor-keeps-defaulting-to-the-right-side)

[Related Kb (How to change monitor settings)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307873)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [**Hardware Profiles**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308577).

Comment: Sounds good, but I haven't been able to make it work yet.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because every time you dock, it gets a new hardware profile. On my dell, there's an option in bios to reduce the instances of that happening which makes all docks identify as the same dock id and eliminates such behaviour. Maybe there's an equivalent setting that might help.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows XP, in the Display Properties (in the Control Panel), on the screen tab you can re-arrange your monitor layout.  Just click and drag the monitors into the configuration you would like to use.

Comment: This is what I'm doing.  I want this setting to stay across when I dock.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the desktop and select Properties > Settings.

If you drag the representation of the secondary monitor to the left of the primary one in the graphic at the top it should do what you want.

I see that this is what you are doing. This should work, I can't think off the top of my head why it wouldn't remember the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [TaskBar PRO](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm), which claims to support this configuration.