# Multi Monitor setup goes crazy after locking/unlocking Vista machine

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors, ultramon

My Vista Business machine, running Ultramon, has three monitors attached. When I lock the machine, the monitor layout stays correct. When I unlock it, I watch as all my screens flicker (as they are being re-configured), and Vista chooses some crazy layout for the monitors. The most recent one is below, but it's never consistent.

Any ideas what might cause this? It's Vista Business, with UltraMon 3.0 (exiting Ultramon makes no difference).

[image: Crazy Vista]

Answer (score 0):

See my answer from [Second monitor on Laptop — external monitor keeps defaulting to the right side](https://superuser.com/questions/3014/second-monitor-on-laptop-external-monitor-keeps-defaulting-to-the-right-side).

Vista's Transient Multimonitor Manager may be causing your problem. Do you have the Transient Multimonitor Manager running? Look in Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Task Scheduler > Task Scheduler Library > Microsoft > Windows > MobilePC > TMM.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a go and let you know what happens

Comment: Hmm, no luck unfortunately. I disabled the task in the scheduled tasks manager and it definately unlocked quicker but everything still went crazy again.

Comment: Are you using ATI Control Center or the NVIDIA equivalent?

Comment: I know its old, but I was using neither. It was an Intel one.