# Monitor position moves when I reboot; any way to fix that, or dynamically set it?

Tags: windows-xp, display, multiple-monitors

I've got Windows XP running with an NVIDIA GeForce 9400GT (with two monitors) and a DisplayLink adapter for a total of three monitors.

During each reboot the third (DisplayLink) monitor changes its position to the far right monitor.  I actually want it located under the first monitor to the left slightly (-504,1028)

After each boot its position moves to (2960,536).  This is a real pain, and I either need to run some software to move it back, or find a way to get Windows to keep those settings.

I've updated this question to describe it a little better with pictures.  I also found a similar post here, but it was Vista, and solved when they upgraded to Windows 7.  I can't upgrade.

[image: Bad-Desktop]

This is what the desktop arrangement looks like after I reboot.

[image: Good-Desktop]

I then have to fix it and move the #2 monitor to this bottom left location.  Upon rebooting, it returns to the first arrangement.

Here is a link to a similar issue:

> [Multi Monitor setup goes crazy after locking/unlocking Vista machine](https://superuser.com/questions/54108/multi-monitor-setup-goes-crazy-after-locking-unlocking-vista-machine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The freeware [Display Changer](http://www.12noon.com/displaychanger.htm) is a command-line utility that can configure all the properties of a monitor, including its relative position to the primary monitor.

For example, to move a specified monitor currently positioned on the right of the primary to the left of it:

> dccmd.exe -monitor="Dell 2009W(Digital)" -left

As another example, to list all monitors:

> dccmd -listmonitors

You could write a script that creates the preferred monitor layout, and set it to run automatically after login in Start menu / Programs / Startup.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  It worked, I'll just run a script that moves it... it's FREE!!! big plus.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're in need of [UltraMon's Display Profiles](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/display_profiles.asp).

> Display profiles make it easy to
>   switch between different desktop
>   configurations. A profile stores the
>   display mode, position and state
>   (enabled/disabled) of each monitor, as
>   well as which monitor is primary
>   (changing the primary is only
>   supported on Windows 2000/XP and
>   later).
>
> If your computer is used by more than
>   one person, you can use display
>   profiles to set up custom display
>   configurations for each user. **Whenever
>   a user logs in, his or her display
>   settings will be applied.** Windows XP
>   Fast User Switching is supported.

[image]

UltraMon is not free (US$39.95 for a single license), but it is well worth it for the [features](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/).

Comment: Good suggestion, however the free route is better for me.  I like some of the features they are advertising.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend **[PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm)**, one of the best solutions for multi-monitor environments. You'll get much more out of your setup, especially since you're using different display adapters (which I suppose is the cause for this hickup).

> PowerStrip provides advanced,
>   multi-monitor, programmable hardware
>   support to a wide range of graphics
>   cards - from the venerable Matrox
>   Millennium I to the latest ATI Radeon
>   HD series. It is the only program of
>   its type to **support multiple
>   graphics cards from multiple chipset
>   vendors, simultaneously**, under every
>   Windows operating system from Windows
>   95 to the x64-bit edition of Vista. A
>   simple menu that pops up from the
>   system tray provides access to some
>   500 controls over your display
>   hardware, including sophisticated
>   color correction tools, period level
>   adjustments over screen geometry, and
>   driver independent clock controls. A
>   powerful application profiler can
>   detect when programs are launched and
>   respond by activating specific display
>   settings, gamma adjustments,
>   performance switches and even clock
>   speeds - returning everything to
>   normal when the program closes.
>   In-game gamma hotkeys let you light up
>   the darkest hallways during game play,
>   and hardware control over refresh
>   rates - with floating point precision
>   - ensure you're never stuck at just 60Hz no matter what OS you're using. A
>   quick setup wizard gets you up and
>   running with minimal fuss, extensive
>   context-sensitive help is available
>   for all controls, and live updates are
>   supported to ensure you're always
>   running the latest release. Finally,
>   an assortment of system and
>   productivity tools - among them,
>   extensive diagnostics, PCIe and AGP
>   device configuration, EDID decoding,
>   desktop icon management, a system idle
>   thread, Windows resource monitoring,
>   an anti-burn-in orbiting option,
>   physical memory optimization, an
>   on-screen display, and the most
>   advanced monitor support in the
>   industry - round out the compact 1MB
>   package.

[image]

[image]

PowerStrip is shareware ($29.95), try before you buy.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I think the free solution was really what I was looking for.  I have used powerstrip in the past to make my PC work with my projector, and I'm just not sure I want to spend money on another license just for this minor problem.